# Redirection in Pyramid after POST

Tags: javascript, pyramid

I am trying to do this simple(?) thing:

- in a test page ("**/test**") send some parameters to the server using POST
- when the view detects some those parameters, redirect to home ("**/**")

I can get this to work but only if I post the values using a form, it does not work if I run a javascript function calling a **xmlhttprequest**. I used the cookiecutter-starter and just added some lines.

**__init__.py**

```
from pyramid.config import Configurator

def main(global_config, **settings):
    """ This function returns a Pyramid WSGI application.
    """
    config = Configurator(settings=settings)
    config.include('pyramid_chameleon')
    config.add_static_view('static', 'static', cache_max_age=0)
    config.add_route('home', '/')
    config.add_route('test', '/test')
    config.scan()
    return config.make_wsgi_app()
```

**views.py**

```
from pyramid.view import view_config
from pyramid.httpexceptions import HTTPFound,HTTPSeeOther

@view_config(route_name='home', renderer='templates/mytemplate.pt')
def my_view(request):
    print("in my view")
    return {'project': 'project'}

@view_config(route_name='test', renderer='templates/jg.pt')
def y_view(request):
    prm_0 = request.POST.get("prm_0",None)
    prm_1 = request.POST.get("prm_1",None)
    if prm_0 and prm_1:
        print("parameters present")
        return HTTPFound(location=request.route_url("home"))
    else:
        print("no parameters found")
    return {}
```

**templates/jg.pt**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:tal="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/tal" xml:lang="es" lang="es">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>n</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function postit(){
        console.log("pompom");
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", '/test', true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8");
        xhr.send("prm_0=898&prm_1=603");
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    using XMLHttpRequest..
    <br/>
    <button onclick="postit()">through xmlhttprequest</button>
    <br/>
    wrapped in a form...
    <form method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="prm_0" value="3455">
        <input type="hidden" name="prm_1" value="6778">
        <button type="submit">in-form</button>
    </form>
</body>
```

When i press the button for the xhr i see in browser development tool 2 requests:

- `name=test`, `status=302`, `type=text,html`
- `name=localhost`, `status=200`, `type=xhr`

I can see in the console that the view callable for home is called (prints "in my view") but it does not render.

Now, when i press the form button i see in browser development tools many requests, being the most important:

- `name=test`, `status=302`, `type=text,html`
- `name=localhost`, `status=200`, `type=document`

and this time it does render the home page.

I tried adjusting the xhr so the headers look like the other request.

#### Request header sent using **xhr button**:

**test page**

```
POST /test HTTP/1.1 
Host: localhost:6543 
Connection: keep-alive 
Content-Length: 19 
Pragma: no-cache 
Cache-Control: no-cache 
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8 
Origin: http://localhost:6543 
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1 
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Safari/537.36 OPR/54.0.2952.54 
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded 
Referer: http://localhost:6543/test 
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br 
Accept-Language: es-419,es;q=0.9 
Cookie: pdtb_active=performance
```

**home page**

```
 GET / HTTP/1.1
 Host: localhost:6543
 Connection: keep-alive
 Pragma: no-cache
 Cache-Control: no-cache
 Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
 Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
 User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Safari/537.36 OPR/54.0.2952.54
 Referer: http://localhost:6543/test
 Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
 Accept-Language: es-419,es;q=0.9
 Cookie: pdtb_active=performance
```

#### Now using the **form button**:

**test page**

```
POST /test HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:6543
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 21
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Origin: http://localhost:6543
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Safari/537.36 OPR/54.0.2952.54
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Referer: http://localhost:6543/test
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: es-419,es;q=0.9
Cookie: pdtb_active=performance
```

**home page**

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:6543
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Safari/537.36 OPR/54.0.2952.54
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Referer: http://localhost:6543/test
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: es-419,es;q=0.9
Cookie: pdtb_active=performance
```

They look the same!

Why is one interpreted as xhr and other as document?

I am thinking that if I get the xhmbutton generated request to be treated as document it may be rendered, am I right? Is this it? I think I read somewhere that the page is not rendered because of the raised exception (httpfound) but if it is so, how or when will it work?

In [Calling another view in Pyramid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7048235/calling-another-view-in-pyramid) some suggested using "render_to_response" or "subrequests", I tried without success and looking at the examples, none of them uses a declarative style for the views, what makes me think that the response that these options generate cannot be well-handled by the renderer.

What is the correct way of accomplishing this? Should I stick to forms? Why does form works but the other does not?

Duplicate? There is a little but important difference to
[Calling another view in Pyramid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7048235/calling-another-view-in-pyramid)
being that in my case I use the declarative style and the return values of the views go through the renderer defined in the decorator. I think that makes the answers of the other thread unfit for this one.

Comment: Please add the content of your `templates/mytemplate.pt`. I suspect you do not have a variable in it to render the value returned from `my_view`.

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer in the pylons-discuss mail group. If i understand correctly the POST made from javascript is not the same that the POST made using the form. For this to work, javascript has to make the redirection.

changing the js script to redirect after completion it works well:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function postit(){
    console.log("pompom");
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", '/test', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", 1);
    xhr.send("prm_0=898&prm_1=603");
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            window.location.replace("/");
        }
    };
}
</script>
```

Comment: The POST made from javascript is actually the same POST, more or less - it's just that your Javascript receives the response and and is, err, responsible for handling it. It's the same as getting a normal 200 response with a HTML blob - if you submitted a form the browser will display a page, if you requested it with Javascript you're responsible for displaying it

Comment: i should have written "POST made from javascript is not HANDLED the same that the POST made using the form.."